# How can I rewrite HTML at the HTTP server level?

Tags: nginx, proxy, http, https

I'm building a personal website using Nginx and I'd like to have the option of serving the same content over both HTTP and HTTPS. However, the content management system I'm using stores a lot of the URIs as HTTP. This results in a lot of mixed content when using HTTPS, and eventually results in entire pages being served over HTTP.

I'm considering using persistent Perl script to act as a proxy and rewrite HTML as it is served. The alternative seems to be finding or writing plugins for each Web software package I install.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't configure your CMS to only generate relative links, try the [HTTPSubModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubModule). *This module can search and replace text in the nginx response.*